# jQuery data-drawer-trigger onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I open this data drawer when I assigned it to another button on click event? I've tried to change the attribute but it's not working. Check the jsfiddle please.

```
$("#new_button").attr("aria-expanded","true");
```

**JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/mhasan09/9mrbq7g0/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the following attributes to your new button, like so:

```
<button data-drawer-trigger aria-controls="drawer-name" >
  Another Button
</button>
```

If you want to set in the JavaScript you can just use:

```
let button = document.getElementById("new_button");
button.setAttribute("data-drawer-trigger", true);
button.setAttribute("aria-controls", "drawer-name");
```

and give an `id` to the button, like so:

```
<button id="new_button" >
  Another Button
</button>
```

Comment: no But I wan't to open it with jQuery on click. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can use jQuery to add those attributes for you.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Yes, check above. You can do it in vanilla JavaScript, no need for jQuery. Here's a fork of your jsfiddle with a working example https://jsfiddle.net/q30bd72j/